# OS X: How to speed-up Java/Swing GUI?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have a Mac mini with 2GHz-Core2Duo/2GB RAM and a HP-Notebook running Windows 7 with identical hardware. For our Java desktop application I'm using Quaqua and Windows look and feel, respectively. On OS X the whole application feels much more sluggish than the one running on Windows 7, especially the rendering.

Are there some options for OS X to speed-up the GUI?

Update: I've set the VM property apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz to true and false but this did not change the subjective performance on OS X 10.6.

Comment: When did you buy your mac-mini ?

Comment: At the same time as the notebook - approx. 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Did You try disabling Quaqua and using core Swing LAF instead? If it's faster than the fault is on Quaqua's implementation side. If you find this being true, but wanting more native experience I would recommend: [Mac Widgets for Java](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) and building separate interface for Mac from ground up.

Comment: No, it is not noticeable faster.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://www.appletell.com/apple/comment/a-breath-of-graphics-life-for-your-older-mac/ It is a software accelerator for your graphics chip. **Use with caution**.
If you Google mac-mini graphics performance you will see that the previous generation macs had slower graphics performance.

Comment: I don't think that the general graphics performance is bad on OS X, just Java/Swing applications feel quite sluggish.